# Arduino Serial not printing any more characters

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I run the code bellow and checked the serial to see that it only printed "Initializing SD Card" then an enter with "Done SD" and then stops

Full code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define SD_PIN 10 //Pin at CS
#define BUZZER_PIN 3
#define TEMP_PIN A2

File sampletext;
int tempVoltage;
int celsius;
char *fileName;

void setup()
{ 

      pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT);

      Serial.begin(9600);
      while(!Serial)
      {
        delay(100); // Wait to open a Serial
      }

      Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
      if (!SD.begin(10))
      {
        Serial.println("Failed SD card");
        return;
      }

      Serial.println("Done SD card");

      sprintf(fileName, "%s_%s.txt", __DATE__, __TIME__);
      sampletext = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
      if(!sampletext)
      {
        Serial.println("Failed to write to file");
        return;
      }
      Serial.println("Setup Done. Exit Serial to close program");
    }

    void loop()
    {
      if(!Serial)
      {
        sampletext.close();
        return;
      }
      tempVoltage = analogRead(TEMP_PIN);
      celsius = ((tempVoltage/1024.0)*5000)/10;
      sampletext = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
      sampletext.println(__DATE__ );
      sampletext.print(__TIME__ );
      sampletext.print("Temp = ");
      sampletext.print(celsius);
      sampletext.print("C");

}
```

Strange thing is that it supposed to print fully "Done SD Card" But stops half way. I have already tried the Fixed encoding option but it does not work.

What would be my solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sprintf` after the `print("Done SD card")` is trashing memory because you did not declare any space to receive the filename characters:

```
char *fileName;
```

That is a pointer to some memory, and it is initialized to 0.  So the `sprintf` is writing the filename characters to address 0.  Urk.

Just declare an array that is sufficiently large to hold the complete filename:

```
char fileName[32];
```

This array declaration can also be passed as the `char *` argument to `sprintf`.  However, you should use the `sprintf` variant that knows when to stop writing:

```
snprintf(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%s_%s.txt", __DATE__, __TIME__);
```